# How to pass manual pre-defined android device id?

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to pass a manual device id without passing the real device id using getDeviceId()? I want to pass a pre-defined device id in my app. I am just playing with my code and a beginner that's why i am if it is possible to do so. Thanks

Comment: `getDeviceId` is [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId()). You should be using `getImei` or `getMeid`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing getDeviceId(), you can just simply write your own value and assign to a variable for further use.

Answer (score 0):

just pass the value you want to intent of getDevice(), pass your string with usename and pass add another string as deviceid and pass it,simple.